# Why is this height matching function not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.listing .listingContent').height($('.listingImage1 img').height() + 50);
});
```

so that I can have text below two absolute positioned toggleable images. On page load `.listingImage1 img` is 480px tall, and `.listing .listingContent` is 483px tall, not 530px like it should be. I think it has something to do with the auto height of `.listingImage1 img`  but I can't figure it out honestly, nothing relates to the 3px.

When I resize the window `.listing .listingContent` becomes 530px like it should be, due to this almost identical function

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.listing .listingContent').height($('.listingImage1 img').height() + 50);
});
```

so I don't get it. It doesn't replicate in codepen even though the code is the same. I uploaded it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzdzj_PQTt6md05NSU1aR2Z6TWc/view?pli=1), refreshing once or twice displays the behavior.

Is there a better way of doing this with the same markup? I can't use a lot of the methods I'm finding online, because the images are generated by a CMS, so it has to be two img elements. I can place them anywhere though. I was thinking maybe I could use append somehow but then the fade effect is lost.

---

```
<article class="listing">
        <ul class="listingContent">
            <li class="listingImage1">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/H3OjxUy.png" />
            </li>
            <li class="listingImage2">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/sjptNd9.png" />
            </li>
            <li class="listingTitle">
                foo
            </li>
            <li class="listingPrice">
                foo
            </li>
            </ul>
</article>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".listing").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).find(".listingImage2,.listingImage1").fadeToggle();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).find(".listingImage2,.listingImage1").fadeToggle();
    });
});

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.listing .listingContent').height($('.listingImage1 img').height() + 50);
    });
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('.listing .listingContent').height($('.listingImage1 img').height() + 50);
    });

.listing {
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .listingContent {
        position: relative;
        li {
            position: absolute;
        }
        .listingImages1, .listingImages2 {
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            right: 0px;
        }
        .listingTitle {bottom: 25px;}
        .listingPrice {bottom: 0px;}
        .listingTitle, .listingPrice {
            top: auto;
        }
        .listingImage2 {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVeGqO

Comment: Are you sure that there's no other css affecting it? Maybe there's padding or margin of 3px

Comment: It appears to be working in Firefox 30. `console.log( ... );` on the height of both the image and the listing content returns 500 and 550.

Comment: @Don it works in firefox for me as well actually. Strange. Both Opera and Chrome have the problem though.

Comment: @JSelser there's nothing unfortunately. I'm stumped.

Comment: @MartyJannetty See my answer (and comment about why timeout's not the safest choice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is not fully loaded yet in Chrome. Instead, change the code (still inside doc.ready) to fire in the image's onload:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //It will only run when the browser has the image's loaded height
        $('.listingImage1 img').load(function() {
            $('.listing .listingContent').height($('.listingImage1 img').height() + 50);
        })
});
```

EDIT: Fixed error with `load` function syntax

Comment: That definitely sounds like a better way to do it. I'm getting a syntax error on that though, "Unexpected token (". I went through each bracket and it seems like everything matches up though. I don't know enough about jquery to debug :/

Comment: @MartyJannetty Whoops, sorry I used the wrong syntax for `load`. Should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `.outerHeight()`. In your case, `.height()` might not return what you are looking for. You may need the paddings and margins and perhaps even borders, which is where `outerHeight()` comes into play.

If you can, give the image a height and width, based on the dimensions of the image used - that way, the browser will - already on page load - be able to calculate the size of the image and thus the size of the surrounding block.

Finally, in rare cases, you may find that if there are certain modifications done to the view upon loading the page, such as which would influence the geometrics of your page, then perhaps your script which determines the height, runs too early. If this is the case, you can wrap the call in a `setTimeout()` call set to a delay of 1ms. This will cause the browser to render the element in the next "round", after finishing its initial rendering.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    // place code here
    // make sure any variables used are in scope at this point
}, 1);
```

Please note that in such a case, different systems and browsers may behave very differently, as rendering will depend on the performance on the system and the browser the page is rendered on/in.

Comment: @MartyJannetty don't use timeout. That's only working because it *happens* to run after Chrome loads the image but it's not a guarantee. It could be the timeout's not long enough on someone else's system. See my answer

Comment: I agree with Don. I totally forgot about `.load()`. My solution may work, but his is a more elegant way to do it.